# How to create sequence if not exists

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2

I tried to use code from [Check if sequence exists in Postgres (plpgsql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905868/check-if-sequence-exists-postgres-plpgsql).

To create sequence if it does not exists. Running this code two times causes an exception:

> sequence ... already exists.

How to create sequence only if it does not exist?

If the sequence does not exist, no message should be written and no error should occur so I cannot use the stored procedure in the other answer to this question since it writes message to log file every time if sequence exists.

```
do $$
begin

SET search_path = '';
IF not EXISTS (SELECT * FROM pg_class
             WHERE relkind = 'S'
               AND oid::regclass::text = 'firma1.' || quote_ident('myseq'))
  THEN

SET search_path = firma1,public;

create sequence myseq;

END IF;

SET search_path = firma1,public;

end$$;

select nextval('myseq')::int as nr;
```

Comment: `If sequence does not exist ..  if sequence exists.` Please clarify what you want to do in each case.

Comment: Postgres 9.5 will have `create sequence if not exists` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createsequence.html

Answer (score 66, accepted):

#### Postgres 9.5 or later

[`IF NOT EXISTS` was added to `CREATE SEQUENCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) in Postgres 9.5. That's the simple solution now:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS myschema.myseq;
```

But consider details of the outdated answer anyway ...
And you know about `serial` or `IDENTITY` columns, right?

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-sql-function/9875517#9875517)

#### Postgres 9.4 or older

Sequences share the namespace with several other table-like objects. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html)

> The sequence name must be distinct from the name of any other
>   **sequence, table, index, view, or foreign table** in the same schema.

Bold emphasis mine. So there are three cases:

1. Name does not exist. *-> Create sequence.*
2. Sequence with the same name exists. *-> Do nothing? Any output? Any logging?*
3. Other conflicting object with the same name exists.  *-> Do something? Any output? Any logging?*

Specify what to do in either case. A `DO` statement could look like this:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _kind "char";
BEGIN
   SELECT relkind
   FROM   pg_class
   WHERE  oid = 'myschema.myseq'::regclass  -- sequence name, optionally schema-qualified
   INTO  _kind;

   IF NOT FOUND THEN       -- name is free
      CREATE SEQUENCE myschema.myseq;
   ELSIF _kind = 'S' THEN  -- sequence exists
      -- do nothing?
   ELSE                    -- object name exists for different kind
      -- do something!
   END IF;
END
$do$;
```

[Object types (`relkind`) in `pg_class` according to the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html):

> r = ordinary table
>   i = index
>   S = sequence
>   v = view
>   m = materialized view
>   c = composite type
>   t = TOAST table
>   f = foreign table

Related:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

Comment: Excellent answer. IIRC sequences used to have problems with not being fully schema-qualified in older versions (before 9.1 ?), causing them to "leak" into the "global namespace". I' not sure though, could have been a glitch on my side ;-[

Comment: @wildplasser: Doesn't ring a bell here, maybe it slipped my attention.

Comment: Could have been a glitch. Too broad search_path settings (plus a lack of explicit schema qualifying) could have been the cause, for instance...

Answer (score 14):

I went a different route: just catch the exception:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
        CREATE SEQUENCE myseq;
EXCEPTION WHEN duplicate_table THEN
        -- do nothing, it's already there
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

One nice benefit to this is that you don't need to worry about what your current schema is.

Comment: only annoying piece, is the extra dependency. I am getting this error. `PG::InternalError: ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/plpgsql.so": /usr/lib/postgresql/plpgsql.so: undefined symbol: MakeExpandedObjectReadOnlyInternal
`

Answer (score 10):

If you don't need to preserve the potentially existing sequence, you could just drop it and then recreate it:

```
DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS id_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE id_seq;
```

Comment: except that if it already exist, it is most likely in use. `PG::DependentObjectsStillExist: ERROR:  cannot drop sequence activities_id_seq because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  default for table activities column id depends on sequence activities_id_seq
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
`

Answer (score 3):

Postgres doesn't have `CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS` and if the table has default value using the sequence if you just drop the sequence, you might get error:

> ERROR: cannot drop sequence (sequence_name) because other objects depend on it SQL state: 2BP01

For me, this one can help:

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ALTER COLUMN id DROP DEFAULT;
DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS <sequence_name>;
CREATE sequence <sequence_name>;
```

Answer (score 0):

The information about sequences can be retrieved from `information_schema.sequences` ([reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/infoschema-sequences.html))

Try something like this (untested):

```
...
IF not EXISTS (SELECT * FROM information_schema.sequences
    WHERE sequence_schema = 'firma1' AND sequence_name = 'myseq') THEN
...
```

Comment: No information is "stored" in objects of the [`information_schema`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/information-schema.html). That's just a collection of (rather convoluted) views on the system catalog to supply the information according to the SQL standard. If you need guaranteed portability across different RDBMS or across versions, use `information_schema`. Using the objects in the system catalog - schema [`pg_catalog`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalogs.html), where *actual* information is stored - is generally faster by an order of magnitude.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter You're right, it was a bad choice of word. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a function to clean all tables in my database application at any time. It is build dynamically, but the essence is that it deletes all data from each table and resets the sequence. 
This is the code to reset the sequence of one of the tables:

```
perform relname from pg_statio_all_sequences where relname = 'privileges_id_seq';
if found then
  select setval ('privileges_id_seq',1, false) into i_result;
end if;
```

Hope this helps,

Loek

I am using postgres 8.4, I see that you use 9.2. Could make a difference where the information is stored.

Comment: The question seems to be about *creating* a sequence, not resetting it. Also, please consider [this \[faq\] posting on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed) about signatures and taglines.

Comment: I read the question that the main concern is how to avoid the arousal of noise. Andrus knows about creating the sequence as he points to a question about that. Your answer is already a perfect solution for the question as a whole. I just wanted to be friendly and provide him an alternative method. The extra information is there to show that it works. I will read the posting about meta etc. shortly.