# Sequence name taken from variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

**How do I create a new sequence taking its name is from a variable?**

Let's take a look at the following example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_value(_name_part character varying)
  RETURNS INTEGER AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    result bigint;
    sequencename character varying(50);
BEGIN
    sequencename = CONCAT('constant_part_of_name_', _name_part);
    IF((SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS INTEGER) FROM pg_class
        WHERE relname LIKE sequencename) = 0)
    THEN
       CREATE SEQUENCE sequencename --here is the guy this is all about
       MINVALUE 6000000
       INCREMENT BY 1;
    END IF;
    SELECT nextval(sequencename) INTO result;
    RETURN result;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Now, let's say I want a sequence with _name_part = 'Whatever', so I type:

```
SELECT get_value('Whatever');
```

If sequence `constant_part_of_name_Whatever` does not exist, my function should create it and take a value; if it exists it should only take a value. However, I created sequence `constant_part_of_name_sequencename`.

How do I put the value of the variable in sequence definition to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The currently accepted answer has a number of problems. Most importantly it fails to take the **schema** into account.

Use instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_value(_name_part text)
  RETURNS bigint AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _seq text  := 'constant_part_of_name_' || _name_part;
BEGIN

CASE (SELECT c.relkind = 'S'::"char"
      FROM   pg_namespace n
      JOIN   pg_class     c ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
      WHERE  n.nspname = current_schema()  -- or provide your schema!
      AND    c.relname = _seq)
WHEN TRUE THEN           -- sequence exists
    -- do nothing
WHEN FALSE THEN          -- not a sequence
   RAISE EXCEPTION '% is not a sequence!', _seq;
ELSE                     -- sequence does not exist, name is free
   EXECUTE format('CREATE SEQUENCE %I MINVALUE 6000000 INCREMENT BY 1', _seq);
END CASE;

RETURN nextval(_seq);

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/90111/5)

#### Major points

- Your test was needlessly expensive and incorrect. You need to take the schema into account. A sequence of the same name can exist in another schema, which would make your function fail.
  I use the current schema as default, since you did not specify otherwise. Details:

  - [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777)

- You also need to be aware that the name of a sequence conflicts with other names of other objects in the same schema. Details:

  - [How to create sequence if not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752885/how-to-create-sequence-if-not-exists/13753955#13753955)

- `varchar(50)` as data type is pointless and may cause problems if you enter a longer string. Just use `text` or `varchar`.
- [The assignment operator in plpgsql is `:=`, not `=`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462322/the-forgotten-assignment-operator-and-the-commonplace)
- You can assign a variable at declaration time. Shorter, cheaper, cleaner.
- You need dynamic SQL, I am using `format()` with `%I` to escape the identifier properly. Details:

  - [INSERT with dynamic table name in trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914325/insert-with-dynamic-table-name-in-trigger-function/7915100#7915100)

- `concat()` is only useful if `NULL` values can be involved. I assume you don't want to pass `NULL`.
- `VOLATILE` is default and therefore just noise.
- If you want to return NULL on NULL input, add `STRICT`.

Comment: My function was pretty simple, because the database I'm running is not really complicated. However, writing things properly from the very beginning is definitely a good habit, so I'm gonna use your answer and look into topics provided in your links. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @spoko: I updated the function once more. Slightly more speed & elegance. Added a fiddle and some more explanation.

Comment: There's an inherent race condition when checking for existence through `pg_*` views. it's not necessary anyway, you may just call `nextval(seq)` and process the non-existence error in an exception clause. At least `nextval` will block if another session is busy dropping or creating the same sequence.

Comment: @DanielVérité: Provoking an exception doesn't remove the race condition. And, [quoting the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING): `A block containing an EXCEPTION clause is significantly more expensive to enter and exit than a block without one. Therefore, don't use EXCEPTION without need.` Would widen time frame for race. One could add `FOR SHARE` to the `SELECT` to prevent concurrent `DELETE` (never tried it). But there is no medicine against a concurrent `CREATE SEQUENCE`. Best keep the transaction small ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thanks for your participation here. I know some time has already passed, but I hope you'll see this anyway. The code above works absolutely fine with Postgres 9.3. However, when I run it in Postgres 8.3.23, I get `syntax error at or near "CASE"` and ^ mark pointing at the beginning of the CASE word in your code. Do you know what do I need to add/remove/change to make it work?

Comment: @spoko: The procedural [`CASE` construct in plpgsql was introduced with pg 8.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS). Not to be confused with the [SQL `CASE` expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE)! Replace with `IF` (or preferably upgrade to a current version).

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope this work for you.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_value(_name_part character varying) RETURNS INTEGER AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    result bigint;
    sequencename character varying(50);
    v_sql character varying;
BEGIN
    sequencename = CONCAT('constant_part_of_name_', _name_part);
    IF((SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS INTEGER) FROM pg_class WHERE relname LIKE sequencename) = 0)
     THEN
     v_sql :=  'CREATE SEQUENCE '||sequencename||' 
       MINVALUE 6000000
       INCREMENT BY 1;';
       EXECUTE  v_sql;
    END IF;
    SELECT nextval(sequencename) INTO result ;
    RETURN result;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Comment: It did, that was what I was looking for. However, I allowed myself to slightly improve your answer, I hope you don't mind ;).

Comment: This function still has a number of problems. I provided another answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_value(_name_part character varying) RETURNS INTEGER AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    result bigint;
    sequencename character varying(50);
BEGIN
    sequencename = CONCAT('constant_part_of_name_', _name_part);
    IF  (select exists(SELECT relname FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind = 'S' and relname = ''''||sequencename||'''') = false )
    THEN
    execute 'CREATE SEQUENCE '||sequencename||'MINVALUE 6000000 INCREMENT BY 1';
    else
    END IF;
    execute 'SELECT nextval('''||sequencename||''')' INTO result;
    RETURN result;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```